# How do I make a JZ become a JMP?

Tags: assembly, ida

I'm a super beginner programmer (not even?) trying to edit a client. I'm using IDA Pro (free) to do this. I have to make a slight modification to my client. The specifics of this problem I have posted on [this forum.](http://forum.ragezone.com/f921/windows-8-10-client-support-1126357/index3.html#post8847892) Though I am posting here as well in the hopes of a faster response, and perhaps to see what knowledge I can learn from a variety of sources.

To put things simply, at the address you see in my picture I am trying to change that "jz" in to a "jmp" or "jump", without conditions. Though, to be honest, I have no idea how to do this!

I've fiddled with the program for hours and I've searched online but the answer seems to elude me. How does one actually edit this so it changes "jz" to "jmp"?
The more details and explanations, the better.

Thanks in advance. [Here is a picture for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg9yD.png)

Comment: Welcome to machine language. You need to use the instruction encodings. [Here is jmp](http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/jmp.html). [Here is jz](http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/jz.html).

Comment: Edit > Patch Program > Assemble.

Comment: On the lowest level you just swap out the opcode (probably `0F 84` to `90 E9`) . As to how you do that in IDA, I have no idea. Especially if you want to do that in the file itself.

Comment: Assuming RMB->Synchronize With->Hex View-A is enabled, just click on the target instruction in the disassembly, then switch to Hex View, and its bytecode will be highlighted. You can then look at the bottom left corner of the window, which shows the 'current offset in the input file'. Use that in a hex editor to patch the file (maybe `74` to `EB`).
You can also do RMB->Edit right in Hex View and the changes will be reflected back in the disassembly, but IDA iirc does not support File->Produce->EXE file in this way; the best you can do is a .DIF file.

Answer (score 0):

Much simplier to replace opcode in hex editor.
Before you can try this, test your substitution in IDA.
Enable showing opcode bytes in Option->General->Disassembly->Number of opcode bytes.
At first, go to same addressof `jz` in hex view and press F2 to start editing. When you finish, press F2.
Then refresh your disassemble window.

Comment: I have similar situation to OP. I tried to change a `jnz` to a `jmp` in IDA using Edit -> Patch Program -> Assemble. In the resulting binary, `0f 85 33 01` changed to `e9 34 01 00`. Looking at links from commenter above, seems the first half is correct. But I am confused: how can `0f 85` describe both `jnz` and `jne`? And what is `33 01` and why would it be changed to `01 00`? Is this an error? It looks fine in the flow chart view. Sorry for bloody noob questions.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. IDA was correct. It added 1 to the jump length because the instruction is 1 byte shorter, but we jump relative to start of next instruction. I changed to `90 e9` (`nop` + `jmp`) instead because it's more concise. Still confused about how the choice between `jnz` and `jne` works though.